# Identify affected tables during application Run - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, data-analysis

I have scenario to Identify the tables and columns affected during various transactions happening through an application. I need a way to capture details of Table, column affected in database during application run. The application is a desktop application where bussiness layer is Java and backend is in SQL Server 2012.

I have already tried by creating triggers on all tables. These triggers would insert the details of Table, column affected into a common table. so at the end of the day this table would give me the information I need.
But this can be messy when there are too many tables with large number of columns.

```
 Table name|column Name|old value|new value|action (insert/update/delete)|transaction type
```

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are very expensive and not scale properly. So, you should avoid them in most cases including your scenario. However, in order to know what is going on your databases the best solution IMO is to use Adam Machanic sp_whoisactive. This is the stored procedure which can run periodically and captured the system state at the moment of the execution.

Comment: Thanks sp_whoisactive is helpful. But It wont give the details at the level at which i a m looking for. I wont to understand what data has changed after each activity in the application.